# PHP call function from another file

Tags: php

The following code works fine on localhost, but when I upload it on server
it doesn't.

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    function test($tmp){
        return "returned value: " . $tmp;
    }
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
    include("functions.php");
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    echo test("value");
?>
```

The server doesn't even show errors, although I have enabled it:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

The PHP versions are the same.

Comment: Include functions.php in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you include the Config.php in your Index.php?

And I'm using this to display my errors.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not try on server. I tried on localhost, it was working fine.

```
Try This

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

OR

There can be file path not found issue.
```